# Positive integers $\gt 5$ that cannot be expressed as the sum of a semiprime and a prime

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and  $n \gt 5$ so that $$n \neq \text{prime} \times \text{prime} + \text{prime}$$

So far I only found $n = 10$. Are there more?

Comment: Related: Chen's Theorem (please see Wikipedia).